# How to apply rule css to div with php

Tags: php, css

I want to apply a css property to a div but don't know how to do it using php. I have a variable called rollover, when it is off, the button would change opacity: 1 to make this visible. How do I do it?

This is the code:

```
$button_style = "letter-spacing: " . $a['button_letter_spacing'] . ";";
      $button_style .= " font-size: " . $a['button_font_size'] . ";";
      $button_style .= " color: " . $a['button_color'] . "; border-color: " . $a['button_color'] . ";";
      if($a['rollover'] == off)
      $button_style .= " opacity: " . 1 . ";";
```

But with $button_style don't work. Because the container that I want to change the opacity property, called button_container, is a div.

```
<?php if ($a['button'] != ''): ?>
      <div class="button_container <?php echo $a['align']; ?>" style="<?php echo "top: " . $a['button_top']; ?>; ">
        <a href="<?php echo $a['button_link']; ?>" class="button" style="<?php echo $button_style; ?>"><span><?php echo $a['button']; ?></span></a>
      </div>
```

In this part of the code you can see the container (button_container) to which you need to change the opacity property when rollover is off.

How I can do this?

I just want that when the variable rollover is off, the opacity property button_container change its value to 1.

Comment: `div.button_container > a.button:hover`

Comment: The best way is to differentiate between cases using [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) of [if/else](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) clauses. On every case add a different class, and target it in your css. Inline styling is not recommended because it's ugly and usually interferes with the .css you want to write (or somebody wants to overwrite)...

Comment: too messy this is not a good design pattern php